# Google Places API Attributes

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying to determine if the Google Places API is suitable for a restaurant review website I'm working on (disclaimer: I'm not a developer so please excuse my lack of knowledge here).

Specifically, looking at https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details for support, I'm trying to determine if the Places API includes the following restaurant-specific attributes in its database that we could query: cuisine type (i.e. Indian, Brunch, American) and/or neighborhood (i.e. Marina, Mission, Financial District).  As an example in Layman's terms, if we were to use the Google Places API, would users on our site be able to search for Indian restaurants in the Financial District and see restaurants that meet that criteria?

Thanks,
Jaydon

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make a search using the 'type' `restaurant` and enter in the search the term `indian`, as for the location you could use a `radius` 
In layman's terms yes you can, but the neighborhood would be determinated from one central location in a radius format (wouldn't fallow the specific outline of the actual neighborhood) and the type of food would have to be included in the search terms, you could automatically add that, in other words, you can ask the end user to specify the cuisine he is looking for (multi choice)  that way you add that cuisine automatically within the search terms.